# Simplest way for SSH connection between two pcs outside local network

Tags: networking, ssh, remote-desktop

*The problem*:
I have a stronger desktop pc and a weaker notebook. I would like to work remotely in  Visual Studio Code, using the hardware of the stronger pc everywhere, also outside
the local network of the desktop pc.

*The progress so far:*

- 1. There are two great tutorials about how to use Visual Studio Code remotely ([1](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview) and
     [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sakjpegUQsk)) via SSH.
- 2. There are many great tutorials how to use an SSH tunnel, but it seems to be complicated to buy a DynDNS, change the router

Is there any way to simplify this process of remotely connecting two computers in networks that can't freely communicate with each other?

Comment: I've reworded your question because software recommendations are off-topic and it would probably get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use [ZeroTier](https://www.zerotier.com/) to create a virtual network. That network will use separate IP addressing independent from your main Internet connection. You can then install ZeroTier clients on both computers and join them into the network (with private networks you'll have to approve them in the web browser). ZeroTier will take care of punching holes in the firewalls etc. Just remember to use IP addresses in the ZeroTier network.

Comment: @Uwe.Schneider Hamachi maybe. How exactly is it unstable?

Comment: In remote development using Visual Studio Code, ZeroTier is breaking down every 5 min and needs to reload.

Comment: @Uwe.Schneider Are you sure it's a ZeroTier issue? Are other connections breaking every 5 minutes as well?